# Image software for creating a repetitive background of seamless tiles

Tags: image-editor

I want to create a background for a website of mine. The image should be able repeat seamlessly so the background can be scaled to any size.

For example, It should [look like this site](https://skribbl.io/).

I have no knowledge in any image software besides MS paint.

So what software should I use to make something like that more easy? Does maybe gimp has a feature to make an image like this or some other free software?

Example result I want to create:

[image: Example image of the pattern like background]
<sub>(source: [skribbl.io](https://skribbl.io/res/background.png))</sub>

Comment: Try searching on “animated gif software”.

Comment: @EricShain I think I didnt described it very well what I want. I want the background, not the animated gifs. I mean that the background has like a pattern that loops. For example there is half a car on the left side and exactly on the other side is the other half so you can loop the picture to fill a large screen. Edit: [Here is the background image of this site](https://skribbl.io/res/background.png)

Comment: Try searching on “seemless pattern software”.

Comment: https://www.designer.io/en/tutorials/graphic-design/how-to-design-seamless-pattern/

Comment: Maybe the [`background-repeat:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat) CSS option is what you're after – so the half car on the left "docks" to its couterpart on the right of the previous one? If you really want *software* instead, please specify what OS it should run on, at what your price margin is.

Comment: I think that the magic word that you are looking for is **tiled** rather than loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend [Paint.NET](https://www.getpaint.net/) with the [Seamless Helper Plugin (direct download)](http://boltbait.googlepages.com/SeamlessHelper.dll). After installation of Paint.NET, you need to copy that DLL file to `C:\Program Files\paint.net\Effects\SeamlessHelper.dll`.

Here's how easy it is:

1. Create a new picture with even pixel length. I use 200x200 px here.
2. Draw something on the center horizontal and vertical lines, like so:

[image: First result]

3. From the Effects menu, choose Seamless helper. The picture will then look like this:

[image: Second result]

4. Go on painting.

[image: Third result]

5. Repeat it on your Website

[image: Final result]